# How to I add a leading numeric identifier (not necessarily zero) to a character string in r

Tags: r

I apologize if this is a duplicate, I've searched through all of the "add leading zero" content I can find, and I'm struggling to find a solution I can work with.  I have the following:

```
siteid<-c("1","11","111")
modifier<-c("44","22","11")
df<-data.frame(siteid,modifier)
```

and I want a modified `siteid` that is always six (6) characters long with zeroes to fill the gaps. The Site ID can vary in `nchar` from 1-3, the modifier is always a length of 2, and the number of zeroes can vary depending on the length of the site ID (so that 6 is always the final modified length).

I would like the following final output:

```
df
#  siteid modifier mod.siteid
#1      1       44     440001
#2     11       22     220011
#3    111       11     110111
```

Thanks for any suggestions or direction. This could also be numeric, but it seems like character manipulation has more options...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vocabulary here is *left pad* and *paste* here is one way using `sprintf()`::

```
df$mod.siteid <- with(df, sprintf("%s%04d", modifier, as.integer(siteid)))

# Note: 
# code simplified thanks to suggestion by Maurits.
```

**Output:**

```
      siteid modifier mod.siteid
1      1       44     440001
2     11       22     220011
3    111       11     110111
```

**Data**:

```
df <- data.frame(
  siteid   = c("1", "11", "111"),
  modifier = c("44", "22", "11"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

**Extra**: If you don't want to left pad with `0`, then using the `stringi` package is one option: `with(df, paste0(modifier, stringi::stri_pad_left(siteid, 4, "q")))`

Comment: Or do everything in one `sprintf` call: `with(df, sprintf("%s%04d", modifier, as.integer(siteid)))`

Comment: I like this, thank you. I've amended it a little to include `df$mod.siteid<-ifelse(nchar(siteid)<6,with(df,sprintf("%s%04d",modifier,as.integer(mod.siteid))),siteid)` to account for complete siteids where they exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
siteid<-c("1","11","111")
modifier<-c("44","22","11")
df<-data.frame(siteid,modifier, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$mod.siteid = paste0( df$modifier, 
                        formatC( as.numeric(df$siteid), width = 4, format = "d", flag="0") )

df

#   siteid modifier mod.siteid
# 1      1       44     440001
# 2     11       22     220011
# 3    111       11     110111
```